# Is it possible to set value of property defined at C# to javascript

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to set value of property defined at C# to javascript...

c# Code.

```
public int val { get; set; }
```

Now i want to set val property at java script function

Comment: Take a look at this link   http://iridescence.no/post/Sharing-Variables-Between-JavaScript-and-C.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a `<% Response.Write( val )%>` , or `<%= val %>` in the .aspx page if you wanted something quick and dirty.

**Edit**
If you want to go the reverse. No, it's not really possible. You might look into WebMethods, but that's not directly what you want to do.

Comment: You want to set the C# value from the JavaScript? If so, I read your question the exact opposite way and Ash did as well.

Answer (score 2):

Not implicitly.

You can register a startup script with this class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stax6fw9.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to se a property on a class from javascript or a javascript variable from a C# property? The former isn't possible directly as the C# code isn't available on the client.  The latter can be done on the server before the response is sent to the client, but how would depend on whether you are doing web forms or ASP.NET MVC.

Ex: to set javascript value from a C# property using MVC/Razor

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jsVariable = '@Model.CSharpProperty';
</script>
```

Comment: i am using asp.net webform not mvc.

Comment: @jats The syntax would be `var jsVariable = '<%= PageProperty %>';` (though you could omit the quotes if it's a numeric value).  Note, though, based on your comments elsewhere, you can't do the reverse, i.e., set the page property from javascript on the client.  You'd need to do some AJAX or include code to take a form value, perhaps hidden, and set it on postback.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do that. asp.net is a serverside technology and javascript is clientside.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I think the question is about using "Properties" in Javascript like you can do in  C# if you want to syntactically hide a method or function with a variable assignment?

If that is the case then yes. You can use "Properties" in Javascript. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_(programming)#JavaScript